# My React native app is not running on physical device

Tags: react-native, apk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U1OY.png)

My React native app is not running on a physical device.it's showing some Gradle error.
I check many articles but cant finds any soulation.
please help on out from this error.

Comment: hi, after attaching your device, run this command on terminal "adb devices"

Comment: and check attached devices

Comment: What error do you face?

Answer (score 0):

You can also connect to the development server over Wi-Fi. You'll first need to install the app on your device using a USB cable, but once that has been done you can debug wirelessly by following these instructions. You'll need your development machine's current IP address before proceeding.

Open the command prompt and type ipconfig to find your machine's IP address (more info).

1. Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
2. Open your React Native app on your device
3. You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following steps will fix that.
4. Open the in-app Developer menu.
5. Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host & port for device.
6. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081).
7. Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.
   Please Check complete on [official site](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device) as well. **[Other Best link](https://aboutreact.com/how-to-run-react-native-app-on-real-device-android/)**